Find the lowest element of a set
The problem
If n is a natural number, and $a_n$ is the number of integers in the interval $[n \sqrt{2}, n\sqrt{3}]$. Lowest
element of the set $\{a_n | n ≥ 7\}$ is...?
my idea
I thought of starting to check some numbers...If $n=7=> a_7=3, n=8=> a_8=2$ and from there $a_n$ starts increasing
I did some code in C++ and found out the answer is 2, which means we have to show that $n > 8=> a_n > 2$, but I don't know how.
I don't know what to do from here. Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
Examining the definition yields $$a_n=\lfloor n\sqrt 3 \rfloor -\lceil n\sqrt 2\rceil +1$$
Now, for any real $x$, we easily see $$ \lfloor x \rfloor≥ x-1\quad \&\quad \lceil y \rceil≥x+1$$
Which implies that $$a_n≥n(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)-1$$
We easily deduce that $$n≥13\implies a_n≥3$$ so we need only test $n≤12$, and we are done.

Is something wrong with my calculation for $n=10$ is good enough.  $n\sqrt 3 - n\sqrt 2 \ge a_n$ so if $n(\sqrt 3 -\sqrt 2) \ge 3$ it's enough to have $n \ge 10$?

Didn't claim the bounds were sharp, didn't need that.  But...an upper bound is irrelevant here.  knowing that the upper bound is big doesn't tell you that the thing itself is big.

For $n \ge 7$ we have interval length $n (\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2) \ge 2.224$. So the interval length is over 2, which means each $a_n$ is at least $2$. And since you found one where it is $2$, that's the answer.


I thought of starting to check some numbers...If n=7=>a7=3,n=8=>a8=2 and from there an starts increasing

$a_n$ starts increasing because the interval $[n\sqrt 2, n\sqrt 3]$ increases in length so you can in general fit more integers in a longer interval.
If an interval is at least $k$ long you can fit at least $k$ integers between the endpoints.  That is, in the interval $[b, c]$ where $c \ge b+ k$ we can fit in the integers $\lceil b\rceil, \lceil b+1\rceil, ... \lceil b+(k-1)\rceil$ as $\lceil b+(k-1)\rceil \le b+k \le c$.
So if $n\ge 7$ we have $n\sqrt 3 - n\sqrt 2 = n(\sqrt 3 - \sqrt 2)\ge 7\times (\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2) > 7 \times 0.3 = 2.1 > 2$. So $a_n \ge 2$.
So... if $n \ge 7$ then $a_n \ge 2$ and $a_8 =2$ so $\min a_{n; n\ge 7}$ has to be $2$.
.........
You might be wondering how if longer intervals can in general hold more integers, then how can we have $a_7=3 > 2 =a_8$ when $8(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2) > 7(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)$?
Well, as the "buffers between integers can be small we might be able to fit in an extra integer.  For example $[5.9,8.2]$ has $8.2-5.9=2.3 > 2$ we can stuff in at least $2$ integers but as $5.9$ to $6$ and $8$ to $8.2$ are smaller than $1$ we can shove in one more.  But we could also have $[5.1,7.9]$ has $7.9-5.1 = 2.8 > 2$ so we can shove in at least $2$ integers, we can't shove in and more as the "buffers" from $5.1$ to $6$ and from $7$ to $7.9$ add up to $1.8 > 1$ we don't have the room.
But the most extra we'll be able to fit in is one.
By the way.  To find out when you can no longer have $a_n \le 2$ and we must have $a_n \ge 3$ or when we can no longer have $an \le k$ and we must have $a_n \ge k$ we can do that by trying to solve $n\sqrt 3 -n\sqrt 2 \ge k$ so $n \ge \frac {k}{\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2}\approx \frac k{0.31783724519578224472575761729617}$.  So if $n\ge \frac 3{0.31783724519578224472575761729617}\approx 9.4$ or in other words if $n\ge 10$ we have $a_n \ge 3$ and if $n \ge \frac {10}{0.31783724519578224472575761729617}\approx 31.46$ or in  other words if $n \ge 32$ we have $a_n \ge 10$.

"you can fit at least k integers" - Do we care? Isn't that the opposite of what we're interested in? We don't want to maximize, we want the minimum.

We do care because we have to show that $a_k$ can never be equal to $1$. "you can fit at least k integers"  "least" is a minimum.  If we can fit in at least $k$ then the MINIMUM can not be less than $k$.  So, yes.  We most certainly do care.  Indeed that's the very heart of YOUR answer.  When you say $a_k \ge 2$ we are saying we always fit at least two integers in and.... actually, I am utterly confounded how you can think this is the opposite or have anything to do with maximimizing when it's obviously about minimizing.

Sorry I was unclear. I'm not talking about the "at least". I'm talking about the "you can fit". That sounds like you're trying to fit as many as you can. Especially since you later do exactly that: "we might be able to fit in an extra integer". It's rather "you must fit". Although I'd really stay away from "fit" and say "If an interval is at least k long it contains at least k integers".

Well, I think the monkey wrench in this is the "How can $a_8 < a_7$ if the interval is getting longer" and "well, if $a_8$ is smaller than $a_7$ then how do we know there isn't any $a_k < a_8$?"
